# Excel VBA sreach

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a piece of code (VBA) that search through a sheet and finds matches then shows up the last matching row in some text boxes.
I put this code in a button,and want to make it to stop each time it finds an occurrence instead of finding the last one and stop.

here's the code:

```
Private Sub cmdFindNext_Click()
Dim lastrow
Dim myfname As String
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
myfname = txtUsername.Text
For currentrow = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(currentrow, 3).Text Like "*" & myfname & "*" Then

txtHost.Text = Cells(currentrow, 2).Text
txtUsername.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3).Text
txtPassword.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4).Text
txtUser.Text = Cells(currentrow, 5).Text
txtDepartment.Text = Cells(currentrow, 6).Text
txtPosition.Text = Cells(currentrow, 7).Text
txtFormerusers.Text = Cells(currentrow, 8).Text
txtCompany.Text = Cells(currentrow, 9).Text

End If
Next currentrow
txtUsername.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: put stop the line before End If or just after the if line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using `If .Cells(currentrow, 3).Text Like "*" & myfname & "*" Then` since you are searching for wildcard, it will enter this `If` condition on every try.

The code below will execute one "**find**" on every click of the button, when you reach the end, it will restart. (you can remove it by modifying the first `If startrow < 2 Or startrow >= lastrow Then`)

```
Option Explicit 

Public startrow                 As Long

Sub cmdFindNext_Click()

Dim lastrow                     As Long
Dim currentrow                  As Long
Dim myfname                     As String

With Sheets("Sheet2")

    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' reset the start row if first run, or finished scanning entire range
    If startrow < 2 Or startrow >= lastrow Then
        startrow = 2
    End If

    myfname = txtUsername.Text

    For currentrow = startrow To lastrow
        If .Cells(currentrow, 3).Text Like "*" & myfname & "*" Then

            txtHost.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 2).Text
            txtUsername.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 3).Text
            txtPassword.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 4).Text
            txtUser.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 5).Text
            txtDepartment.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 6).Text
            txtPosition.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 7).Text
            txtFormerusers.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 8).Text
            txtCompany.Text = .Cells(currentrow, 9).Text

            startrow = startrow + 1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next currentrow
End With

txtUsername.SetFocus

End Sub
```